# How can I verify that one of two methods was called using Mockito?

Tags: java, mockito

Suppose I have a class with two methods where I don't care which is called...

```
public class Foo {
    public String getProperty(String key) {
        return getProperty(key, null);
    }
    public String getProperty(String key, String defaultValue) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Both the below (from another class, still in my application) should pass my test:

```
public void thisShouldPass(String key) {
    // ...
    String theValue = foo.getProperty(key, "blah");
    // ...
}

public void thisShouldAlsoPass(String key) {
    // ...
    String theValue = foo.getProperty(key);
    if (theValue == null) {
        theValue = "blah";
    }
    // ...
}
```

I don't care which was called, I just want one of the two variants to be called.

In Mockito, I can generally do things like this:

```
Mockito.verify(foo, atLeastOnce()).getProperty(anyString());
```

Or:

```
Mockito.verify(foo, atLeastOnce()).getProperty(anyString(), anyString());
```

Is there a native way to say "verify **either one or the other** occurred at least once"?

Or do I have to do something as crude as:

```
try {
    Mockito.verify(foo, atLeastOnce()).getProperty(anyString());
} catch (AssertionError e) {
    Mockito.verify(foo, atLeastOnce()).getProperty(anyString(), anyString());
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `atLeast(0)` in combination with `ArgumentCaptor`:

```
ArgumentCaptor<String> propertyKeyCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
Mockito.verify(foo, atLeast(0)).getProperty(propertyKeyCaptor.capture(), anyString());

ArgumentCaptor<String> propertyKeyCaptor2 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
Mockito.verify(foo, atLeast(0)).getProperty(propertyKeyCaptor2.capture());

List<String> propertyKeyValues = propertyKeyCaptor.getAllValues();
List<String> propertyKeyValues2 = propertyKeyCaptor2.getAllValues();

assertTrue(!propertyKeyValues.isEmpty() || !propertyKeyValues2.isEmpty()); //JUnit assert -- modify for whatever testing framework you're using
```

Comment: I like it! I thought `ArgumentCaptor` was deprecated, but actually it just seems the constructor is deprecated, your `forClass` method is still favoured. I presume `atLeast(0)` is because you need to call `verify` in order to attach the `ArgumentCaptor`?

Comment: Exactly right. I use `ArgumentCaptor` a lot for these types of things (though not this use-case exactly), it's very handy. Until I looked it up just now I didn't even know `atLeast(0)` was possible -- in earlier versions of Mockito it wasn't.

Comment: I just noticed that `ArgumentCaptor` should not be used with stubbing as per the JavaDoc. I think I might need to do that as I'm stubbing both `getProperty` variants. I'm also confused where in the above snippet I need to call `thisShouldPass` or `thisShouldAlsoPass`. Surely the `ArgumentCaptor` can't be attached *after* I have run these methods?

Comment: All of this code goes after the method(s) are run, just where calls to `verify()` would typically go.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, if you're calling `verify` on a "getter" of any sort, you're assuming too much about the implementation. Mockito is generally designed for flexible tests (compared to "brittle" test that need to change even if the code is correct); your test should care more about *whether* the value is correct as opposed to *which* methods were used to get that value. A better solution might be to *stub* both getters to return a predictable value, and then use a normal assertion against the same value to ensure it plumbs through to the correct place.

```
when(mockFoo.getProperty("bar")).thenReturn("bar value");
when(mockFoo.getProperty("bar", anyString())).thenReturn("bar value");
// ...
assertEquals("bar value", new SystemUnderTest(mockFoo).getBarProperty());
```

Mockito's documentation spells this out:

> Although it is possible to verify a stubbed invocation, usually it's just redundant. Let's say you've stubbed `foo.bar()`. If your code cares what `foo.bar()` returns then something else breaks (often before even `verify()` gets executed). If your code doesn't care what `get(0)` returns then it should not be stubbed.

That said, if this is a pattern you're required to support (or a method call with both overloads and side-effects) you can get a lot of information via [`Mockito.mockingDetails`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mocking_details) and [`MockingDetails.getInvocations`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/MockingDetails.html#getInvocations()), including invocations as of Mockito 1.10.0. You would need to loop through the Invocation objects to check against multiple methods.

```
boolean found = false;
Method method1 = Foo.class.getMethod("getProperty", String.class);
Method method2 = Foo.class.getMethod("getProperty", String.class, String.class);
for (Invocation invocation : Mockito.mockingDetails(foo).getInvocations()) {
  if (method1.equals(invocation.getMethod())
      || method2.equals(invocation.getMethod()) {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
assertTrue("getProperty was not invoked", found);
```

Note that this *second* solution is a little dangerous, as it does not benefit from automatic refactoring tools built into IDEs, and may be harder to read than some other solutions. (The above may also be missing calls to `isIgnoredForVerification`, `markVerified`, and other niceties.) However, if you foresee needing this frequently across a large codebase, then using Mockito's built-in APIs may afford you much more flexibility than you would have otherwise.

Comment: My code has two paths through it - one uses a `getProperty` and another uses Spring. In my tests, I need to verify that the `getProperty` way was used rather than the Spring way under certain circumstances, because in my real application (when the method is invoked during Spring context initialization) the Spring variables won't be available yet, but they are available in my test.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, `getProperty(String)` calls `getProperty(String, String)` internally.

```
public String getProperty(String key) {
    /*
     * getProperty(String, String) is called anyway.
     * Why not simply verify the occurrence of that?
     */
    return getProperty(key, null);
}
```

Simply verifying the second method would be equivalent to verifying the occurrence of either one or the other at least once.

```
Mockito.verify(foo, atLeastOnce()).getProperty(anyString(), anyString());
```

Comment: Hi John - if I mock the class `Foo`, then surely `getProperty(String)` won't call `getProperty(String,String)` - it will just return the value from the mock (I believe either an empty string or null by default...can't remember)?

Comment: Yes, you're right. One way around that would be to `callRealMethod()`  when `getProperty(String)`.