# Check if a element verifies the condition

Tags: java, unit-testing, java-8, mockito

I've a List of objects. I want to know if some of that object methods were called or not.

i.e.:

```
List<Object> list = ...;
Object first = spy(new Object());
Object second = spy(new Object());
list.add(first);
list.add(second);

callToStringToOnlyOneRandomElement(list);
```

I want to know how can I do the verify part. The test is OK if this happens:

```
verify(first, times(1)).toString();
verify(second, never()).toString();
```

XOR if this happens:

```
verify(first, never()).toString();
verify(second, times(1)).toString();
```

But no in other cases (if `first.toString()` and `second.toString()` are called,
or if neither is called).

> **For context:** The real problem involves threads and race conditions. I want to know if 10 elements are processed directly, and if all the other elements goes to a private queue. Because the calls happens concurrently, there is no order in which elements of the array are processed directly (that's the expected behavior).

Currently, I'm using `Mockito 1.9`

Comment: Add to the list the same object two times and check the method in question was called only once.

Comment: what have you tried? Can you show us some example code which is not working as intended or some sign of research

Comment: The context you have provided and example of XOR - don't they contradict to each other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I verify that one of two methods was called using Mockito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828486/how-can-i-verify-that-one-of-two-methods-was-called-using-mockito)

Comment: @Lino This is a "best practice" question. There isn't a "not working" example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the behavior of threads should not be the subject of unit testing. 
The results may vary to much and the integration test suite is more suited for this kind of scenarios.

If you really have to, you would need to take into consideration both options in the same test method. You cannot combine mockito `verify` calls with the use of logical operators but a little workaround would be:

```
boolean firstOptionFail = false;

try{
   verify(first, times(1)).toString();
   verify(second, never()).toString();      
}catch (MockitoException e) {
    firstOptionFail = true;
}

if(firstOptionFail){
  verify(first, never()).toString();
  verify(second, times(1)).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that Mock libraries can help you with this out of the box. I would rather write my mock objects to verify this or follow Andriy Simonov advice (add one element twice and check that method was called only once)

All in all, race conditions are among the worst things for unit/auto testing, so it is always better to design them out.
When ever you test race conditions you create test which may randomly pass and fail (if it pass it doesn't 100% means your function is working properly, it may also mean that due to some random things race condition you were trying to test just didn't happen).

Answer (score 0):

A list allows you to put in the *same* element multiple times. So your test could be as easy as this:

```
List<Object> list = ...;
Object spy = spy(new Object());

list.add(spy);
list.add(spy);

callToStringToOnlyOneRandomElement(list);

verify(spy, times(1)).toString();
```