# Mockk method invocation verification: can I verify that one of two possible methods was invoked?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

I want to check if either [`HandlerThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread)'s `quit` or `quitSafely` method was invoked (exactly once and only one of these two). Is it possible using [Mockk](https://mockk.io/)?

Comment: No, this is not possible with mockk, but looks like a good feature to do. Do you know if it is possible in other mocking frameworks?

Comment: Nope, because it seems that in Mockito it is done quite crutchy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828486/how-can-i-verify-that-one-of-two-methods-was-called-using-mockito

Comment: Added an issue https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/196 (please don't expect it happen too soon. I spend weekend per 4-6 weeks to fix mockk things)

Comment: You probably can do the same workaround with try/catch as Mockito. It is ugly, but better now then nothing. I will need to think about syntax, redo a lot of stuff inside to make it happen. It is not a small change(although I find it interesting to do)

Comment: No worries!
If you could make an answer with contents of the commentaries it would be just great. This way I could mark an answer as accepted, while within comments it's impossible.